# JavaScript if-Statement; when true it should play a sound

Tags: javascript, if-statement, audio, local, twitch

So im working on a twitch bot in JS, for now he connects with the chat and can recognize a command (like !twitter), but when someone writes !sound it should play a sound but I always see solutions with HTML and it should only work with JS and the Twitch Chat and run on my local PC. ( Sorry for bad english, its not my native language). Does someone has a solution or a advice for me?

```
var tmi = require('tmi.js');

var options = {
    options: {
        debug: true
    },
    connection: {
        cluster: "aws",
        reconnect: true
    },
    identity: {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    },
    channels: ["DiggnC"]
};
var client = new tmi.client(options);
client.connect();

// Connect Message in der Console
client.on('connected', function(adress, port){
console.log("Adresse: " + adress + " Port: " + port);
client.say("DiggnC", "Der Bot ist nun mit dem Stream verbunden!");
});

client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
  if(message == "!twitter"){
    client.say("DiggnC", "Mein Twitter: https://twitter.com/thetruemitello")}
});

// Abfrage für Sound im Stream
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
  if(message =="!testsound"){
    client.say("DiggnC", "Dies ist eine Testausgabe zur Funktionalität der Audioausgabe");
    //Here it should play the sound on my local PC
  }
});
```

Comment: So, you just need to know how to actually play the sound? Like, you're good with everything else?

Comment: Not really, im new to JS ^^ And the most solutions were a little bit complicated

Comment: FYI. You can only play the sound on the system the bot is running on. Twitch chat won't let you play a sound. Don't think that's what you're asking for, but just so you know.

Comment: @AdamLeBlanc It is supposed to play that sound on my system, if someone in my twitchchat triggeres this command it should play on my pc so they can hear it in the stream

Answer (score 0):

Playing audio is pretty straightforward using the [HTMLMediaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement).

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
  if(message =="!testsound"){
    client.say("DiggnC", "Dies ist eine Testausgabe zur Funktionalität der Audioausgabe");
    //Here it should play the sound on my local PC
    var audio = new Audio("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
    audio.play();
  }
});
```

Try it below:

```js
var audio = new Audio("https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3");
audio.play();
```

I just grabbed the first sample mp3 URL available from Google to use in `Audio`.  You can also use a relative URL to an audio file on your website/PC (e.g. if you have `MyFile.mp3` in the same folder as your javascript file then you'd use `new Audio("MyFile.mp3")`)